# Copy FOLDER to several multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory, subdirectory

I have currently created the following code, it works fine to copy the contents within the folder 'C:\metadata_home\met_source\metadata\' BUT I need to copy the folder as well. When I use the syntax: copy "C:\metadata_home\met_source\" "%%~ff" it throws up an error saying 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

---

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set currentDirectory=%CD%
FOR /D %%g IN ("C:\metadata_home\met_dest\*") DO (
    Pushd %CD%\%%g
    FOR /D %%f IN ("C:\metadata_home\met_dest\*") DO (
        copy "C:\metadata_home\met_source\metadata\" "%%~ff"
    )
Popd
)
```

pause

---

Please help I am banging my head against the wall on this one!

Comment: Well - I'm lost! What do you mean by "copy the folder as well"? Are you trying to copy an entire subtree? If so, why not use `XCOPY` ? I'd hazard a guess that your syntax error is because `COPY` is looking for a `filemask` which it expects after the terminal `\` in the first parameter. Try adding `*.*` after that `\` (and I'd change the `copy` to a `copy /b` if you insist on using `copy` - but `xcopy /e c:\source` is the command to copy the subtree

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xcopy /s C:\metadata_home\met_source\metadata C:\metadata_home\met_dest
```